# Get IBM Bluemix SQL Database service credentials before I bind it to application, is it possible?

Tags: ibm-cloud, sqldb

When I bind SQL Database service to an application I can see credentials from application panel. But in case I've created a service and would like to work with it before I'm binding to any application, is it possible? I haven't find a way to see credentials, only internal tools to work with database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you provision a new SQL Database instance, you need to enter the service details page in bluemix, find the **'Launch'** button to go to the service page which will open up separately. On the service page go to **Set up `-->` Connect Applications `-- >` Connection settings**. You will get all the connection details except the username and password.

If you are not able to resolve the username and password then you have got two alternatives :-

    1. Create a
    **dummy application**
    , bind it to your SQL Database, get the credentials from
    **VCAP_SERVICES**
    , and you can use them externally.
    2. If you are looking for something only on
    **`DB2`**
    then you have another alternative called
    **`DashDB`**
    available in Bluemix. Here the settings are well defined, credentials are clearly available and will work even without binding the service to an application.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.